# error when using webrtc lib into my QT project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, webrtc

I got a webrtc lib that have been compiled, and could be used by my C++ Dynamic Library (.dll) project.

But I got many compiler errors when using webrtc lib with my Qt project, from `WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h` file.

error is at the Line 54-73,this function

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value && std::is_signed<T>::value,
                        absl::optional<T>>::type
StringToNumber(absl::string_view str, int base = 10) {
  using string_to_number_internal::signed_type;
  static_assert(
      std::numeric_limits<T>::max() <=
              std::numeric_limits<signed_type>::max() &&
          std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest() >=
              std::numeric_limits<signed_type>::lowest(),
      "StringToNumber only supports signed integers as large as long long int");
  absl::optional<signed_type> value =
      string_to_number_internal::ParseSigned(str, base);
  if (value && *value >= std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest() &&
      *value <= std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) {
    return static_cast<T>(*value);
  }
  return absl::nullopt;
}
```

the error list

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0028   expression must have a constant value   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h 83  
Error (active)  E0040   expected an identifier  qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h 83  
Error (active)  E0028   expression must have a constant value   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h 91  
Error (active)  E0040   expected an identifier  qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h 91  
Error (active)  E0040   expected an identifier  qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h 128 
Error (active)  E0040   expected an identifier  qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\frequency.h 65  
Error (active)  E0040   expected an identifier  qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\frequency.h 74  
Error (active)  E0040   expected an identifier  qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\video\video_source_interface.h    46  
Error (active)  E0040   expected an identifier  qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\video\video_source_interface.h    54  
Error   C2589   '(': illegal token on right side of '::'    qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\buffer.h 93  
Error   C2589   '(': illegal token on right side of '::'    qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\buffer.h 377 
Error   C2760   syntax error: '(' was unexpected here; expected ':' qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\buffer.h 377 
Error   C2760   syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected ';' qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\buffer.h 377 
Error   C3878   syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'expression_statement' qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\buffer.h 377 
Error   C2760   syntax error: ':' was unexpected here; expected ';' qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\buffer.h 377 
Error   C3878   syntax error: unexpected token ':' following 'expression_statement' qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\buffer.h 377 
Warning C4003   not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\frequency.h 65  
Error   C2589   '(': illegal token on right side of '::'    qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\frequency.h 65  
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\frequency.h 65  
Warning C4003   not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\frequency.h 74  
Error   C2589   '(': illegal token on right side of '::'    qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\frequency.h 74  
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\frequency.h 74  
Warning C4003   not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h 83  
Error   C2589   '(': illegal token on right side of '::'    qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h 83  
Error   C2062   type 'unknown-type' unexpected  qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h 83  
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h 83  
Warning C4003   not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h 91  
Error   C2589   '(': illegal token on right side of '::'    qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h 91  
Error   C2062   type 'unknown-type' unexpected  qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h 91  
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h 91  
Warning C4003   not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h 130 
Error   C2589   '(': illegal token on right side of '::'    qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h 128 
Error   C2062   type 'unknown-type' unexpected  qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h 130 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h 130 
Error   C2589   '(': illegal token on right side of '::'    qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\candidate.h   89  
Error   C2062   type 'unknown-type' unexpected  qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\candidate.h   89  
Error   C2144   syntax error: 'unknown-type' should be preceded by '('  qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\candidate.h   89  
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\candidate.h   89  
Warning C4003   not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   60  
Warning C4003   not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   61  
Warning C4003   not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   68  
Error   C2589   '(': illegal token on right side of '::'    qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   60  
Error   C2760   syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected 'expression'    qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   60  
Error   C2760   syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected ';' qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   60  
Error   C3878   syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'expression_statement' qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   60  
Error   C2589   '(': illegal token on right side of '::'    qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   61  
Error   C2760   syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected 'expression'    qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   61  
Error   C2760   syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected ';' qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   61  
Error   C3878   syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'expression_statement' qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   61  
Error   C2760   syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected ';' qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   64  
Error   C3878   syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'expression_statement' qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   64  
Error   C2589   '(': illegal token on right side of '::'    qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   68  
Error   C3878   syntax error: unexpected token '(' following 'expression'   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   68  
Error   C2760   syntax error: '>' was unexpected here; expected 'statement' qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   68  
Error   C2760   syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected 'expression'    qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   68  
Error   C2760   syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected ';' qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   68  
Error   C3878   syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'expression_statement' qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   68  
Error   C3878   syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'statement'    qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   68  
Error   C3878   syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'selection_statement'  qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   68  
Warning C4003   not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   80  
Warning C4003   not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   81  
Warning C4003   not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   86  
Error   C2589   '(': illegal token on right side of '::'    qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   80  
Error   C2760   syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected 'expression'    qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   80  
Error   C2760   syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected ';' qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   80  
Error   C3878   syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'expression_statement' qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   80  
Error   C2589   '(': illegal token on right side of '::'    qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   81  
Error   C2760   syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected 'expression'    qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   81  
Error   C2760   syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected ';' qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   81  
Error   C3878   syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'expression_statement' qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   81  
Error   C2760   syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected ';' qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h   83  
Error   C1003   error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation   qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib  D:\lib\WebRTC\include\third_party\abseil-cpp\absl\types\optional.h  119
```

the output is as this

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>WrbRTC_Factory.cpp
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\buffer.h(93,24): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\buffer.h(434,2): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'rtc::BufferT<T,ZeroOnFree>' being compiled
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\buffer.h(377,31): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\buffer.h(377,31): error C2760: syntax error: '(' was unexpected here; expected ':'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\buffer.h(377,31): error C2760: syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected ';'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\buffer.h(377,31): error C3878: syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'expression_statement'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\buffer.h(377,31): message : error recovery skipped: ') ?'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\buffer.h(377,31): error C2760: syntax error: ':' was unexpected here; expected ';'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\buffer.h(377,31): error C3878: syntax error: unexpected token ':' following 'expression_statement'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\buffer.h(377,31): message : error recovery skipped: ':'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\buffer.h(377,31): message : error recovery skipped: ') :'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\frequency.h(65,3): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\frequency.h(65,3): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\frequency.h(65,3): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\frequency.h(74,3): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\frequency.h(74,3): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\frequency.h(74,3): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h(83,37): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h(83,37): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h(83,37): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h(83,37): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h(91,37): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h(91,37): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h(91,37): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h(91,37): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h(130,1): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h(128,3): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h(130,1): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\units\data_rate.h(130,1): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\candidate.h(89,14): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\candidate.h(89,1): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\candidate.h(89,1): error C2144: syntax error: 'unknown-type' should be preceded by '('
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\api\candidate.h(89,1): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(60,31): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(61,49): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(68,41): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(60,31): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(60,31): error C2760: syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected 'expression'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(60,31): error C2760: syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected ';'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(60,31): error C3878: syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'expression_statement'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(60,31): message : error recovery skipped: ') >'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(60,31): message : error recovery skipped: ') ) ?'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(60,31): message : error recovery skipped: ') :'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(60,31): message : error recovery skipped: ') ) <='
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(61,49): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(61,49): error C2760: syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected 'expression'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(61,49): error C2760: syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected ';'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(61,49): error C3878: syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'expression_statement'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(61,49): message : error recovery skipped: ') >'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(61,49): message : error recovery skipped: ') ) ?'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(61,49): message : error recovery skipped: ') :'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(61,49): message : error recovery skipped: ') ) &&'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(64,79): error C2760: syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected ';'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(64,79): error C3878: syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'expression_statement'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(64,79): message : error recovery skipped: ')'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(68,41): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(68,41): error C3878: syntax error: unexpected token '(' following 'expression'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(68,41): message : error recovery skipped: '( ('
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(68,41): error C2760: syntax error: '>' was unexpected here; expected 'statement'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(68,41): message : error recovery skipped: '>'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(68,41): error C2760: syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected 'expression'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(68,41): error C2760: syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected ';'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(68,41): error C3878: syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'expression_statement'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(68,41): error C3878: syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'statement'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(68,41): error C3878: syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'selection_statement'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(68,41): message : error recovery skipped: ') ) ?'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(68,41): message : error recovery skipped: ') :'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(68,41): message : error recovery skipped: ') ) )'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(80,41): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(81,57): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(86,50): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(80,41): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(85,1): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'absl::optional<rtc::string_to_number_internal::unsigned_type>' being compiled
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(80,41): error C2760: syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected 'expression'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(80,41): error C2760: syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected ';'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(80,41): error C3878: syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'expression_statement'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(80,41): message : error recovery skipped: ') >'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(80,41): message : error recovery skipped: ') ) ?'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(80,41): message : error recovery skipped: ') :'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(80,41): message : error recovery skipped: ') ) <='
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(81,57): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(81,57): error C2760: syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected 'expression'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(81,57): error C2760: syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected ';'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(81,57): error C3878: syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'expression_statement'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(81,57): message : error recovery skipped: ') >'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(81,57): message : error recovery skipped: ') ) ?'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(81,57): message : error recovery skipped: ') :'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(81,57): message : error recovery skipped: ') ) ,'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\rtc_base\string_to_number.h(83,41): error C2760: syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected ';'
1>D:\lib\WebRTC\include\third_party\abseil-cpp\absl\types\optional.h(119): fatal  error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
1>Done building project "qt_project_for_webrtc_by_using_the_lib.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 2:39 PM and took 01.345 seconds ==========
```

my project config

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: My guess is this requires c++17 and you are using the default c++14. You can fix that in the `C/C++ -> Language` settings.

Comment: Also you should post errors from the Output Tab and not the errors list. The Output Tab is in a better format for text and often more verbose.

Comment: @drescherjm sir,I edit my question,could u help me have a look,I set the C++ 17 last time, and this time I build a new project and then do those step again,but the question is different, it's confusing.

Comment: Stupid windows macros.